# Assigning memory to array of double pointer to string?

Tags: c, arrays

Sorry for my bad english but I have a question for you. I wrote a program with array of double pointer to string for save memory but i have a question. In  calloc for col name pointer is correct? With 'frutta' the program works. Thanks in advance for your help!

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
void inserimento (char **, int);
void output (char **, int);
int main ()
{
char **frutta;
int n,i;
printf("Quanta frutta vuoi inserire?\n");
scanf("%d",&n); //with this I write here number of elements 
//(with 4 for example I write 4 fruit names)
frutta=(char **)calloc(frutta,sizeof(char*));//calloc for col. Name pointer 
//here is correct?
for (i=0;i<n;i++)
frutta[i]=(char *)calloc(n,sizeof(char));//calloc for row
inserimento (frutta,n);
output (frutta,n);
for (i=0;i<n;i++)
free(frutta[i]);
free(frutta);
}
void inserimento (char **frutta, int n)
{
int i;
for (i=0;i<n;i++)
scanf("%s",frutta[i]);//here add name fruits
}
void output (char **frutta, int n)
{
int i;
for (i=0;i<n;i++)
printf("%s",frutta[i]);//here print name fruits
}
```

Comment: No it is not correct and your compiler should have warned you aboit it. (If not, get a better compiler). Read the documentation and see what the two parameters of calloc mean.

Comment: In addition, `frutta[i]=(char *)calloc(n,sizeof(char))` is dubious. There's no natural link between the number of strings and the length of each string.

Answer (score 0):

```
//here is correct?
for (i=0;i<n;i++)
```

Nope this is not. To make it right you have to allocate memory for `n` pointers. (You didn't do the first `calloc` successfully).

```
frutta=calloc(n,sizeof(char*))
```

Syntax was wrong earlier. You have got an warning/error.

Make sure to compiler the programs with all the `-Wall` flag. And don't forget to check every warning you get. That will help you on these cases.

---

From standard **[7.22.3.2](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.22.3.2)**

```
void *calloc(size_t nmemb, size_t size);
```

> The `calloc` function allocates space for an **array of nmemb objects,
>   each of whose size is size**. The space is initialized to all bits zero

Two more things:-

1. Dont cast the return value of `calloc`.
2. Check the return value of `calloc`.
3. Free the allocated memory when you are done working with it.

Yes! I have made one extra point.

Answer (score 0):

```
frutta=(char **)calloc(frutta,sizeof(char*));
```

It's not correct. Compiler warnings exist for a reason. **calloc** needs integer as a first argument, as described:

> void *calloc(size_t nmemb, size_t size);

Answer (score 0):

This is definitely not correct. The first parameter to `calloc` is the number of members and you're passing into it the pointer, which at this point won't have a defined value.

```
frutta=(char **)calloc(frutta,sizeof(char*));
```

Instead, you want to use `n` that you've just read in.

```
frutta=calloc(n,sizeof(char*));
```

Secondly, for the next level down, you probably want something a lot bigger than `n` if you're going to be storing actual strings in there. Your example of 4 would only give you space to store strings that are 3 characters long as you need to include space for the NUL terminating character.

```
frutta[i]=(char *)calloc(n,sizeof(char));
```

You also shouldn't cast the return value of `calloc` (or `malloc`) as it's not needed and can hide errors in your code.